# MySQL CASE WHEN within CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

Cars

```
Make  |  Model  |  Year   |  Color  
Honda |  Accord |  12     |  Red
Lexus |    IS   |  14     |  Blue
```

I receive files like these and have to make the sure header row matches the parameters before I send it off to a php script.

I currently have a SELECT CASE WHEN that checks for other errors such as blanks in the code:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN a.Make = '' THEN '**BLANK**'
ELSE a.Make
END as Make,
```

Is it possible that there's a SELECT within SELECT that I can use to make sure the received files header (and only header) matches our headers?

Comment: Have you tried it? Where's the code?

Comment: You posted some sample data. What do you mean by "headers"? Tables have rows and columns. The columns are named. You mean the "column name" in a file?? or is the file it self a "header" for some detail file?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I've tried this code but it runs the risk of replacing values in all rows, I just want it to replace values in row 1.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't clear. I recommend editing your question to clarify exactly what you're wanting to do. It sounds like you're trying to validate your data in MySQL? You should be validating your data before it even touches the SQL.

Comment: Are you loading values from a text file into the database and then checking to see if some of the column entries are blank? What is supposed to happen when they are blank? How do these get sent to a php script? 

It might be easier to just write a small script in a language like python to do some data sanity checking before loading it into a database -- when you put data in a DB that is bad you will run into problems further down the line.

Comment: @NWest Yea I receive CSV's with column names that match our DB table columns in row 1.  I have to make sure these column values in row 1 match what our DB is defined as.

Comment: @UnknownFury I'm using SQL to validate the data to show where the errors exist, if any, on my local DB before loading it live.  These files are generally 140,000 rows.

Comment: @radicalmatt The files are Windows CSV that I load to a localhost before the files are loaded to php via cmd line.  Eventually a python script will be written but I have to define it in SQL first.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me. But from what I understand, you wanted to have a record that contains the same name like your column headers.

CASE WHEN a.Make = '' THEN '**BLANK**'
     WHEN a.Make <> 'Make' OR a.Model <> 'Model' THEN 'None'
     WHEN . .. ..
    ELSE a.Make
 ...

Comment: Yupp. this can also be one solution for your prob.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to do so. You can just mention your conds here in this case statetment as well. Somthing like

```
CASE
WHEN a.Make = '' THEN '**BLANK**'
ELSE a.Make
WHEN a.Make <> '' AND  a.Make <> 'Make' THEN 'ANOTHER'
ELSE a.make
WHEN a.Model <> '' AND  a.Model <> 'Model' THEN 'ANOTHER'
ELSE a.Model
..... etc.
```

I think this script can work for you.

Comment: I'm trying this but it looks like multiple ELSE commands in 1 CASE produce an error in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try something like :

```
SET @make := (SELECT a.Make FROM cars a WHERE ...);
SET @model := (SELECT a.Model FROM cars a WHERE ...);

IF @make = 'Make' AND @model = 'Model' AND ... THEN
#continue your script
ELSE
#end your script
END IF;
```